# sane on Ubuntu 14-04 doesn't recognize Samsung scanner

Tags: ubuntu, scanner, samsung

I have a Dell-Precision 5510 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and Samsung SCX-4729FW with combined copier+printer+scanner. Samsung is USB-connected directly to the laptop. I can print out my files from the laptop to printer, but when trying to use scanner (via Xsane command or icon) get a response "no device available". I tried to do it using "sudo", but my comp warned me it is dangerous, so i didn't continue.

My /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf doesn't have Samsung SCX blacklisted.
My /home/(myID)/.sane/xsane have these files:

Hewlett-Packard:ScanJet7400c.drc

SAMSUNG:SCX-472xSerieson10.0.0.20.drc

SAMSUNG:SCX-472xSerieson192.168.1.20.drc

SAMSUNG:SCX-472xSeriesonUSB:0.drc

xsane.mdf

xsane.rc

So I guess I have all the right drivers. Still, "no device available"... What can I do about it?

Comment: The problem could be permissions on the USB device. Does `sudo scanimage -L` list the Samsung? (It's safe to run that with `sudo`.)

Comment: @Steve: sudo scanimage -L does not list any scanner...  A command "sane-find-scanner" tells me that  "No SCSI scanners found. ... make sure that you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter." It also is specific on that  "could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)" (and the same on other devices). Also " # No USB scanners found. ...  make sure that # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have set the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved; the credit for guiding me through all my action belongs to my Canadian friend. OK, he pointed me to the website http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/  -- drivers for all the SAMSUNG scanners for all LINUX systems,

Samsung Unified Linux Driver

and I followed their instructions to the tee. They suggest plenty of options; my fist step was

sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

Since I was doing all the stuff in line, I ignored "IPORTANT" and "ALSO IMPORTANT" sections. Then I did

sudo apt-get update

Then I installed the package

sudo dpkg -i suldr-keyring_2_all.deb

and refreshed the repositary.

An important part is to choose the right driver for your specific SAMSUNG; in my case, SAMSUNG SCX-4729 FW, it was

suld-driver-4.01.17 ,

as well graphic interface

suld-configurator-2-qt4